# How to add a 'Copy Files build phase' to my Target

Tags: xcode

I am trying to use a framework that requires me to add a 'Copy Files build phase' to my target.  Does anyone know what this means and how to do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right-Click on your target in XCode, select add "new build phase" and then "new copy files build phase".

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.6. "New build phase" doesn't seem to be an option when I right-click. Any idea how to do this for xcode 4.6?

Comment: It’s in the project settings under Build Phases.

Answer (score 95):

In Xcode 5, you have to click on your **target**, then on **Editor** (menu bar) --> **Add build phase** --> **Add Copy Files Build Phase**:

[image: XCode process to add some "Build Phase"]

Comment: I never would have thought to look in the Editor menu. When I try this, though, the options are greyed out. I guess I'm missing the first item, "click on your target". Where is the target?

Comment: Ah. I found it. I had to click on the tiny triangle next to my project name to display the column listing the targets.

Comment: There's a bug with Xcode where if the Build Phases tab loses focus all the options will be grayed out. You need to do the following: Click Target Name > Build Phases > Click on whitespace below phases > Editor > Add Build Phase

Comment: In my case, clicking "Validate Settings..." helped enable the "Add Copy Files Build Phase" option

Comment: This is totally out of place. Even more so if you consider that the little "x" to remove a phase is next to each phase.

Comment: jesus, apple.. would never look there! thanks a lot for the solution :)

Comment: In Xcode 7.3.1, the menu remains grayed out, regardless of where I click to change the focus. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

A "DIY" answer: Go to Xcode --> Help --> type your query, e.g., "add copy". And Xcode helpfully points you in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 4, the option is in Editor->Add Build Phase.

The Copy Files build phase then appears in the Project Navigator and you can add things to it by clicking the plus.