# XCode 5: Changes to Text File Not Showing Up on Simulator (using Folder References)

Tags: ios, xcode

I dragged a big folder of resources into my Xcode project, selecting

I renamed the files, dragged them into my project (selecting Create Folder References), built, and ran, and files showed up just fine. But now when I make a change, I can see the changes in XCode, but they have no effect when I run unless I do a clean build.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124083/resource-files-not-updating-with-xcode-5

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Xcode doess't detect changes made by edits outside of Xcode. You have to go back into Xcode and touch the files that you have edited. Or do a full build.