# XCode: add build phase is disabled

Tags: ios, xcode6

I want to add [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com) plugin to my iOS project that demands to add `Run script` phase. But no matter what I do -  for *add  build phase* all options are disabled:

[image]

- I select Target -> Build Phases
- I have proper scheme
- My project runs well - no issues,

*I run Xcode 6*

Answer (score 63):

I answer  on my question because took me time to find right solution.

Its really strange that the same issue migrates from old versions to XCode 7+.
I found solution in one of the comments of similar problem:

<kbd>[how-to-add-a-copy-files-build-phase-to-my-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365479/how-to-add-a-copy-files-build-phase-to-my-target)</kbd> (credits to @Paul Solt)

Its a bug, when user selects `Build Pahses` tab, XCode doesn't see that.

*Solution*

- select `Target` -> `Build Phases`
- After, click on any area under search form or better way, just open `Target Dependencies` drop down
- Editor -> Add Build Phase

I hope it will save time to someone instead to read comments ;)

Comment: In my case 'Build Phases' become active when I selected one of compile .m files

Comment: In my case had to click on any of the .cpp files

Comment: I have a project with an external builder and this description did not work for me.

Comment: @user637338 if you downvoted this answer please turn it back, if it doesn't work for you - means this answer is helpless for your case but its not a *wrong* answer.

Answer (score 7):

The upvoted solution did not work for me but there is another - even though the "Editor->Add Build Phase" is grayed out the small "+" in the top left of the "Build Phases" pane is not, and it works.

So select the project in the project navigator
Select the target
Select "Build Phases" in the top bar of the content pane
Click the "+" symbol in the top left of the "Build Phases" pane

Comment: Genius.  I'm in XCode 8 and the other suggestions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maxims answer did not work for me.

I had the same problem and solved it as follows and I opened a bug against apple: issue 22516266 on https://bugreport.apple.com

Here is how I solved the issue for me:

1.) Edit Scheme ...

[image: Edit Scheme...]

2.) In the relevant phase of the schema you can add scripts as Pre-Actions or Post-Action, where you will find "New Run Script Action"

[image: Define Build Process]

I think you pretty much create any workflow you like with this.

Hope that helps.